# Parallel upload of files from a directory in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to write a Python utility function which uploads files from a directory to a destination folder. Although, the documentation provides a snippet with `blob.upload_from_filename()` for a single file and then it jumps to `gsutil -m` solution for multiple files.

So far, I have found only 2 suboptimal solutions:

1. Simple iteration of the single file operation
2. Use of `subprocess` and hardcode the `gsutil` command.

Is there any elegant solution for this issue or should I use Python's `multiprocessing`?

Comment: I'm not very skilled in python but I have a question, why not use the blob.upload_from_filename() in a multi-thread loop? https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: that's what I intend to do if I cannot find any solution, but this comes with more complicated unit and integration testing. Anyway, it sounds really weird to provide a parallel running solution via command line (`gsutils -m`) without any programming alternative.

Comment: Concurrent thread is the key for that. GSUtil do exactly that behind the scene, and in Python. You can achieve it, but the development is not so easy indeed.

Comment: I believe you are looking for large volume uploads and not big size file uploads. The official documentation lists different ways of sending upload requests to Cloud Storage, see if any of it helps your use case.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#uploads

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is looking for this, It has been included in the lastet version of google-cloud-storage with transfer_manager

Here is an example:
https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/9998a5e1c9e9e8920c4d40e13e39095585de657a/samples/snippets/storage_transfer_manager.py